# What are currently (May 2022) the biggest pain points of the Lightning Network?

Tags: lightning-network, scalability

I am wondering what are currently the biggest roadblocks and challenges (maybe also in Bitcoin) that we need to overcome in the Lightning Network protocol. Why are they challenging and why is it so hard to fix them?

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I'm wondering whether it can still be categorized as asking for expertise, or whether it may be a bit too subjective and too time-localized to fit well here. (I'd be mollified were some great answers to appear on this topic, though!)

Comment: Tbh I was also not sure about this place but I am not sure if I know of a  better one

Comment: Would this perhaps be a topic for the lightning-dev mailing list?